# Create table error with Apache Derby database: Syntax error: Encountered "AUTO_INCREMENT"

Tags: sql, coldfusion, derby

I've created a datasource in the Coldfusion Administrator interface for an embedded Apache Derby database. The queries, such as `select`, work fine. However, I can't find a way to create a new table in my database. I couldn't find interface for that, such as in phpmyAdmin, either. that. I've tried to create it by using a SQL query, but then builder complains about syntax errors:

> Error Executing Database Query.
>
> Syntax error: Encountered "AUTO_INCREMENT" at line 1, column 38

**Screen shots:**

[image: ColdFusion Query]
[image: Syntax Error]

Comment: Please attach your create table code and error instead of adding it as pictures

Comment: In Derby the auto increment is defined as such `ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),` See: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/develop/develop132.html

Comment: ok, and primary key the same as in sql? just - primary key(id)?

Comment: omg it works. thanx a lot! coudn't find any inf on that for 2 days, damn!

Comment: Using a web page to create a table in a database indicates that you might not be using the best method to accomplish your goal, or even a good one for that matter.

Comment: oh i'm sure as hell i'm not as i'm a noob. feel free to tell me better ways and also how to delete tables. certain ones not all of them.

Comment: Why Derby? You realize you can use any database with a jdbc driver, right? Standard databases like MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc. have their own IDE's for db modeling, just do a search.